# OSQP solver in Python

Tags: python, solver, quadratic-programming

I have a question about a OSQP (Operator Splitting Quadratic Program)
solver implementation:

I'd like to use this to solve the quadratic problem with 10x10 matrix randomly generated.

I tried the following:

```
import osqp
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse


# Define problem data
P = sparse.csc_matrix(np.random.uniform(1, 10, size=(10, 10)))
q = np.random.uniform(0, 9, size=10)
Gs= np.random.uniform(0, 9, size=10)
print("der Maßstab für Gs:", Gs)
A = sparse.csc_matrix(np.diag(-1*Gs))
l = np.zeros(10)


# Create an OSQP object
prob = osqp.OSQP()

# Setup workspace and change alpha parameter
prob.setup(P, q, A, l, alpha=1.0)

# Solve problem
res = prob.solve()
```

but there are just error with
`ValueError: Workspace allocation error!`

do you have any idea what I did wrong?

It works well when I use solver `cvxopt` and when I use the example code from the website.

I changed a bit but it doesn't work at all.

Comment: https://github.com/osqp/osqp/issues/290 have you looked at this?

Comment: OSQP can only solve convex problems. I.e. P must be positive semi-definite. See the documentation. A random matrix is typically not PSD. You are passing on a problem for which OSQP is not designed.